# What do I do about a power gamer?

Tags: powergaming

I run a game of about six people and we have a generally good time. However, I have noticed recently that one of the players has started building an almost-identical munchkin to something I've seen on GitP's forums, and can find with a quick Google search. That, and this player has started stealing a lot of the center stage because of how brokenly powerful the character is becoming in comparison to everyone else.

How do I deal with this? I don't want to just arbitrarily kill off the character, nor do I want to run the player off.

Comment: Definitely a Dupe as they are both general questions without any real specific information and/or a system.

Comment: @dmsapghetti, welcome to the site!  Your question has been covered here before, quite recently in fact.  I recommend you look at this question: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57656/what-can-i-do-to-prevent-a-player-from-breaking-the-game and at the "powergamer" tag on this site http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powergaming

Comment: @dmspaghetti Give us some specifics (i.e. the exact build) and this question will work fine, currently it's too generic to be answerable

Comment: I think you should re-ask this question stating the used rule system and a link to the exact character build. You could then ask how this character could be challenged or if there is any weakness the designer didn't think about or if there is any obvious rule-patch you could introduce to nerf the character to the same level as the others (most uber-builds depend on some loophole in the RAW). Another angle you could spin this question to make it a better fit would be to describe the problems which occur in your group because of the overpowered character and how to solve them.