# The Templar Prestige Class (Based on the Dragon Age: Origins Knight Templars)

Tags: dnd-3.5e, homebrew, class

This is my idea for a prestige class that i wanted to make for a campaign. Please comment below for any tips or suggestions to make it better.

LINK: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13pqYmmQhtR8dk9qJ2S225oU01J1LTixswC4v7AvNOZ8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: rpg.stackexchange is not meant for discussing homebrew materials. There are plenty of forums where you can find such advice though.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs Both the rules of the network and the history of this particular site suggests you are wrong. Stack Exchange gladly handles *good subjective* questions—those where answers can be backed up with expertise. Game design is absolutely something one can, and members of this site do, have expertise in. And several homebrew-evaluation questions exist on this site without issue. This is on-topic, good subjective, and no duplicate. It might be a bit broad and/or unclear—ideally the question should bring up particular concerns—but overall it’s not unsalvageable like you suggest.

Comment: Are you running the campaign and hoping PCs will take this prestige class? Or are you running the campaign and will be making the PCs' foes take this class? Or is another running the campaign, and you're developing this hoping that the DM will approve it?

Comment: This will likely soon be closed, but all is not lost: As @KRyan mentions, the site *is* capable of evaluating homebrew material, but both *context* and *purpose* are useful when doing so. I've asked for context in the comment above, but providing an *evaluative purpose* is just as helpful: Do you want to know if the class is balanced against other classes, and, if so, which ones, and do you have in mind a [tier](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/38201/8610)? [Do you want to know if it accurately emulates an existing property?](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Templar_Order) That sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are somewhat problematic: Mage Slayer can be taken at 3rd, so this class is available starting at 4th, which is unusual for a prestige class. Not unprecedented, though.

The spell resistance is really bad. A spellcaster will average 10.5 + level against it, so assuming you do start this at 4th, this will have only a 50% chance to resist a spell by someone of your own level. When you consider that spellcasters have many options for ignoring SR, often have bonuses, and enemies are often higher level to begin with, that doesn't look very good. But worse, SR hurts a character at least as much as it helps, since it also blocks beneficial spells, so you risk missing an important buff out critical healing exchange for an unreliable defense.

Finally, replacing all Reflex saved with Fort is... interesting.  Getting to completely ignore a saving throw is kind of a big deal, and that ability is unprecedented. That said, Reflex is the least-important save, so I think it may be OK.

Beyond what it does have, I do think it also lacks something: namely any significant offense or utility. The smite is good relative to smite’s norm, but that isn't saying very much. And it has nothing else. For a class that is almost purely defense, then, it is not great—some resistances but no immunities.