# How to optimize a Sorcerer or Oracle into Tier 1?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, sorcerer, class, oracle

This answer talks about ‘unlocking’ Tier 2 sorcerers and oracles into Tier 1:

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/114432

I’m curious as to what specific alternate class features, feats, race combinations, or other methods are used to achieve this.

Comment: @kryan I couldn’t comment on your answer there, so I made a new question

Comment: Follow-up questions *should* be asked as questions; this is good. Thanks for the heads-up, but Zachiel’s answer seems fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is literally bundled in the answer you linked:

> It basically involves pumping your spells known and taking advantage of options—particularly with paragon surge and mnemonic vestment—that allow you to change your spells known on a day-to-day basis.

The difference between tier 1 classes and tier 2 classes is that tier 1 classes can decide to swap out their current powerful spells with other spells that are needed.

Therefore, if a tier 2 class has an option to change their spells known, they automatically become a tier 1 class by taking that option.

The *[paragon surge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/paragon-surge/)* spell lets half-elves (or humans with the appropriate heritage feat) learn a feat on the spot. Enters the [Extended Arcana](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/expanded-arcana/) feat and boom, you can now cast a spell that you previously couldn't, giving you even more flexibility than your usual Wizard, who needs to rest and memorize in order to swap.

(I'd personally rule that every time you use *paragon surge* to get Extended Arcana you get the same choice of spells you choose the first time you tried this trick.)

a *[Mnemonic Vestment](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/vestment-mnemonic/)* lets you use a scroll without spending it, once per day. Well, that saves you some money I guess but in my book it's not that worse than actually using scrolls, provided that you also lose a magic item slot.