# Building and Pricing a Collapsible Lance

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

I have a player who has specced out to use lances while riding as one of his preferred methods of fighting. He has an efficient quiver and would like to be able to store his lance in the third slot (from the rules it can hold the following):

> The third and longest portion of the case contains as many as 6 objects of the same general size and shape as a bow (spears, staffs, or the like).

Obviously the lance is too big for this section so he asked if it was possible to give it a "collapsible" property, which would effectively allow it to go from the size of staff to the size of a lance in a swift action. As the DM I'm okay with this, but since it's a unique item I want to roleplay him getting this from a smith, and a large part of that involves specific pricing.

The way I see it, it can either go closer to the price of a masterwork item or it is effectively treated as a magical weapon and requires the +1 before it can get the "collapsible" trait. Not entirely sure which would make more sense for this case, looking for any insight.

Comment: Can you indicate your level of experience as a DM?

Comment: I used to DM a lot back in the day for 3.5, this is the first campaign I've run in about 6-7 years though

Comment: Ok, what is the party composition? Specifically, is this character a martial character in a group of casters?

Comment: The party is made up of three mid range characters and a support alchemist. Technically they can all fill any necessary role. Really this player wants to ride his mount and lance things, but also not have to worry about the logistics of carrying around a 10 foot lance at all times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Just double the cost for a custom make item and call it a day

Pathfinder and 3.5 both have the issue of [quadratic casters and linear fighters](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/114432/31402). To that end, your character sounds like a martial type trying to keep pace in a magical world. Per your comment the party they're with is mid-range characters (not sure if these are casters or archers), but regardless, they'll regularly be able to take their full attack actions on their turns while this character would regularly be lagging behind.

A lot of tables don't make archers track their arrows and even if they do, they don't have an issue with the archers having like 5 quivers with them. And for magic-users, they definitely don't have issues with tracking their attack gear.

So to that end, I would simply double the cost of the item since the smith will need to take some time to effectively make a custom item. It's a cost that represents it unique nature, it's not a cost that significantly bites into the PCs funds that they'll need for other magic items necessary to keep pace with the rest of the party.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable compromise and functional in application

Answer (score 0):

A lance is not larger than a spear.  Unless this is a Large lance or something, it should fit in any magical container that can also contain spears without need for any further modification.

I'm unsure why you're punishing a martial character with extra rules and provisos on using already far-too-expensive magic items for what sounds like a mostly roleplaying concern in any case.  There's no inherent penalty to just 'carrying around' a lance as long as it's under his encumbrance, except from a roleplaying perspective.

Punishing players for wanting to do things other than accrue as many +1's as possible with their magic item budget sounds like the opposite of helpful.