# How to make attacks of opportunity with Kineticist Blast at close range via feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I understand that the Kineticist Blast counts as a weapon in certain ways and for certain feats. Given that, is there a way for me to use feats to make opportunity attacks with Blast at close range?

Answer (score 3):

## Take Snap Shot et. al.

There's a line of feats that starts with the feat [Snap Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/snap-shot-combat/) and ends with [Greater Snap Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-snap-shot-combat/) which center around making attacks of opportunity with ranged weapons.  The feats can be pretty good with the right build, but [you're going to struggle if you are blasting as a kineticist](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105540/what-tier-is-the-kineticist); consider taking kinetic blade instead, which will eliminate the need for these feats in your build.

Comment: It’s unclear that Snap Shot’s threatening effect actually works with kinetic blast; kinetic blast may count as a weapon, but can you really be said to be “wielding” it? After all, kinetic blast takes a standard action to use, and Snap Shot doesn’t give you one. Also, I strongly doubt your claim that Snap Shot *et al.* are ever “pretty good,” with any build. That is a **ton** of feats to let you do something you can only ever do if you give up one of the biggest advantages you have as a ranged attacker—and if you’ll be in melee much, you might as well just use a melee weapon and save the feats.

Comment: (All that said, +1 since it answers the question correctly, these are just tangential concerns with your answer.)