# Can targets get out of Weighing Infusion with Strength or Escape Artist checks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, kineticist

Weighing Infusion states:

> This infusion functions as entangling infusion, except it entangles and immobilizes a foe by increasing its weight, rather than surrounding it in elemental matter.

Entangling Infusion allows Escape Artist or Strength checks along with attacking the matter.  I am wondering if because the matter is not present in Weighing that the Escape Artist and Attack checks would also not apply?

Comment: You may be interested in our [guidance on playing kineticists in general](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/105559/4563). In particular, be very careful with void, as it is very limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, *weighing infusion* still lets people attempt Strength or Escape Artist checks to get out of it.

If *weighing infusion* weren’t going to have the same rules for getting out of it that *entangling infusion* has, it would say that. Actually, it probably wouldn’t bother referencing *entangling infusion* at all, because that would be confusing and misleading.

On the other hand, attacking the entangling matter is out, since there is none.